# Qt : Setting a border bottom on QtableView disables selection-background-color

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I currently have something like this in my QtableView stylesheet

```
QTableView::item 
{
     selection-background-color: rgb(85, 85, 127);
     border-bottom: 1px double #8f8f91;
 }
```

Now the problem is the `selection-background-color: rgb(85, 85, 127);` takes effct only if `border-bottom: 1px double #8f8f91;` is disabled. Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify any border attribute if you want suck customization. Is't specific of QSS:

```
border: 0px solid transparent; // Or any other border
```

Comment: That doesnt work. In short if border-bottom is specified then selection-background-color does not work

Comment: Try another selector: `QTableView::item:selected{ background-color: blablabla; }`